# Making <img> unselectable and undraggable at the same works in Firefox but not in Chrome or Opera

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, opera

I have an image, and I want to make it both *unselectable* and *undraggable*. (Not in an attempt to prevent the user from copying)

I can achieve this by

1. Adding a `.noselect` class to the `<img>` tag. As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4407335/6282576).
2. Disabling `pointer-events`. (I'm aware that this also disables `onclick`, but since I don't need to click on this image, I simply don't care.)

```css
body,
html {
  background-color: #181A1B;
  color: white;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.introduction {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.introduction p,
h1 {
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
}

.introduction img {
  border-radius: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.clearfix {
  clear: both;
}

.noselect {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  /* iOS Safari */
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  /* Safari */
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  /* Konqueror HTML */
  -moz-user-select: none;
  /* Firefox */
  -ms-user-select: none;
  /* Internet Explorer / Edge */
  user-select: none;
  /* Non-prefixed version */
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Oxygen';
  src: url('../fonts/oxygen/Oxygen-Regular.ttf');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Amir A. Shabani</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="introduction">
      <img class="noselect" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/amirashabani/shabani.xyz/master/images/profile.png" alt="profile picture">
      <div class="introduction-text">
        <h1 class="noselect">Hi, my name is Amir.</h1>
        <p class="noselect">I'm a backend developer and an avid Linux and FOSS enthusiast.<br/>I enjoy programming and developing software that works efficiently.<br/>Currently, I'm studying Software Engineering at the University of Qom, Iran.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Now this works as expected in `firefox 69.0-1`, but in `google-chrome 77.0.3865.75-1`:

[image: chrome]

I can't drag the image itself, but if I try to highlight the div that contains the image, then I can drag the image. Same thing in `opera 63.0.3368.88-1`:

[image: opera]

And just to show that it works it Firefox:

[image: firefox]

How can I fix this?

I've also used `draggable="false"` in my `<img>` tag, but same thing occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add an empty div over the image with your noselect class on it, it should work pretty cleanly

Edit: or add the image as background image of a div with your noselect class.

Comment: Adding an empty div over the image worked perfectly, thanks.